# How does AWS lambda get triggered by an api request?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-sdk

Im assuming lambda is like the missing piece of the puzzle for a complete api request. So you create the apigateway and then write the lambda function which bridges the gap between taking a request and returning the output of the lambda function as the http response.

I've successfully followed guides on how to set up an API gateway that triggers AWS lambda to do something, but I still don't really understand what is being done.

How is the function `def handler(event, context):` being called by the aws apigateway? How does it get triggered and how is the output of handler sent back?

Comment: Please consider marking the answer below "green" if it covers your question.

Answer (score 2):

You do not need a Lambda "in the middle". Using Lambda Proxy integration in the API Gateway you can receive the full information about the request (endpoint URL, query parameters, etc) in your targeted Lambda `event`.

Have a look at the [following Tutorial](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-create-api-as-simple-proxy-for-lambda.html) how to setup Lambda Proxy integration with API Gateway.

The tricky thing you should care about is the structure of the response that you will return from your lambda_handler. [See the requirements here.](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-integration-settings-integration-response.html)

Answering the question of "how this happens"... In short, when an HTTP request comes to your API endpoint it is automatically routed to the mapped Lambda function. Behind the scenes a new container for the Function is spawned and your request comes to the `event` of the `lambda_handler`. API Gateway by default also creates a CloudFront distribution in front of itself to serve your requests more efficiently. Once your Lambda returns the response, API Gateway parses it and constructs the HTTP response out of it. The nice thing is that all of this is managed by AWS.